# Factorial Program in Python using generator

Tags: python, function, generator, factorial

```
#function
def fact(x):
    a = 1
    b = 1
    if x == 0:
        a = 1
    if x < 0:
        print('enter valid whole number!')
    if x > 0:
        while b < x:
            a = a * b
            b += 1
    yield a
#main
z = input('Enter a number')
g = (fact(n) for n in range (0,int(z)))
print(next(g))
```

When I am running the above program the output is showing a generator object at some block like this:

```
Enter a number4
<generator object fact at 0x03DF6930>
```

Comment: Your `fact` function isn't the generator; it produces one value. Change `yield` to `return`

Comment: Rule of thumb: if your generator only yields once when you call it, then it doesn't need to be a generator. Why not just do `return a`? (If the answer is "because my teacher says I have to write code that uses `yield`", try using it somewhere where it's more useful than this)

Answer (score 11):

`g` is a generator that calls `fact` and yields the results. But `fact` is also a generator. You have two generators, so you need two `next` calls.

```
z = 3
g = (fact(n) for n in range (0,int(z)))
print(next(next(g)))
```

Result:

```
1
```

Alternatively, turn `fact` into a regular old non-generator function, since there's not much point using `yield` if you only need to retrieve a single value from the callable.

```
def fact(x):
    a = 1
    b = 1
    if x == 0:
        a = 1
    if x < 0:
        print('enter valid whole number!')
    if x > 0:
        while b < x:
            a = a * b
            b += 1
    return a
#main
z = 3
g = (fact(n) for n in range (0,int(z)))
print(next(g))
```

Result:

```
1
```

Maybe you're thinking "but what I actually want to do is calculate the first N factorial values in O(N) time (assuming that multiplication of arbitrarily large integers is O(1)), and changing my function to use `return` means that I will have to re-calculate old values a lot. Someone told me that `yield` might improve performance, but my first attempt didn't work, so how am I supposed to do it?". Perhaps they wanted you to write something like:

```
def factorials_up_to(x):
    a = 1
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        a *= i
        yield a

for x in factorials_up_to(6):
    print(x)
```

Result:

```
1
2
6
24
120
720
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this question.  However, my personal preference would be to create an infinite object where each element gets loaded only when it is needed.  User [warnabas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53219130/16372031) suggests a way to do this using the `itertools` library, but it is possible (and simpler) to avoid this.

```
def fac(n, t):
    '''This creates a generator for the sequence of factorial
    numbers.'''

    yield t
    yield from fac(n+1, n*t)

f = fac(1,1)
```

We can then use this generator however we want.  For example, the code

```
z = int(input('Enter a number: ')) +1
for i in range(z):
    print(next(f))
```

prompts the user to input a number and then prints the sequence of factorials up to and including z!.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools


def factorial_generator():
    i, fac = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield fac
        fac *= i
        i += 1

def factorial(n):
    return next(itertools.islice(factorial_generator(), n, None))
```

actually you should to build infinite sequence to make true generator.

Answer (score 0):

```
# factorial function, recursively compute factorial
def fact(n):
    if n==1:
        # base case
        return 1
    else:
        # recursive case
        return n*fact(n-1)

# upto desired number computer the factorial function
def upto(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        yield fact(i)

# call function
f=upto(3)
# print (it will print object not its contents)
print(f)
# to print use __next__ method to show each value
print(f.__next__())
print(f.__next__())
print(f.__next__())
```

Comment: You might improve your answer with a single sentence explaining what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another method to print factorial through generator with function and for loop
Method - 1

```
def fact(n):
value = 1
for i in range(1,n+1):
     value *= i
     yield value
f = fact(int(input('Enter the number : ')))

print(next(f))
print(next(f))
print(next(f))
print(next(f))
```

Output:

```
Enter the number : 4
1
2
6
24
```

Method - 2

```
def fact(n):
value = 1
for i in range(1,n+1):
     value *= i
     yield value

f = fact(int(input('Enter the number : ')))

for value in f:
    print(value)
```

Output :

```
Enter the number : 4
1
2
6
24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_factorial(num):
    factorial = 1
    for x in (i for i in range(num)):
        factorial *= x+1

    return factorial

def main():

    print(get_factorial(5))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

may be that

```py
def recursive_fact(x :int)->int:
    if x == 0:
        yield 1
    yield x * next(recursive_fact(x-1))
```

Result:

```py
print(list(recursive_fact(5)))
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your description of your solution